# Battlelog shows I am not Premium even though I've purchased Premium Edition

Tags: battlefield-3, battlelog

I dont get any of the bonus stuff on battlelog. For example, it says I got 200 something kills with the regular knife but most of them were on the ACB 90 knife. I bought this premium edition the one with the code and game. This was a long time ago but it still doesn't say that I'm premium. I tried contacting tech support but all they say is that im not a member. I get all the in game stuff like assignments and expansion packs though. When people kill me it says im premium, proof from friends. Whenever I try to look at premium stuff, it tells me to buy premium first. It only says I have b2k.

http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/soldier/Your%20Very%20Lazy/stats/861324530/xbox360/

Comment: This is really odd, because you clearly had access to all the content since you've played all add-ons, so it should be impossible that only the B2K symbol is shown. Have you tried to contact the EA BF3 support with the "contact us" button at the bottom of this page: http://help.ea.com/en/battlefield/battlefield-3/ It seems to specifically link the question with your account. Try to explain as specifically as possible that you already have access to the DLC so that you are not disregarded as just not having bought it, like it seemed to have happened before.

Comment: I don't see any other option but contacting support again.

Comment: I still think you should try to contact them again and make it very clear that you have entered the code correctly and do have access to all the stuff ingame. When you get to a decently competent person, that shouldn't be possible to be answered with "you are not premium" again. It clearly is a mistake on battlelog, and I don't see any other option to fix this yourself.

Comment: My brother had the same issue after buying premium, he had to contact support.  Do you still have your receipt? *(if you ordered online, it should be in your inbox)*

Answer (score 4):

Follow these instructions:

1. Open Origin
2. Press "My Games"
3. Find Battlefield 3
4. Hold your mouse on the Battlefield 3 icon
5. Press "i" (down right corner next to "play" text)
6. Scroll down a little to find the "expansions" text
7. Now check that you have those expansion what you have bought (DLC´s)
8. Download them.

And now your are ready to play Battlefield 3 Premium!